# "What's new" updates not working in People hub, but working in twitter app

Tags: 8.0, sync, people-hub, twitter

Using the dedicated twitter app on my lumia 920 I can usually access updates without a problem. However, every now and then, accessing the `what's new` tab in the `people hub` seems to have trouble synching updates. Trying `...` and `refresh` sometimes exits with a message, sometimes throws me back to the start screen, and sometimes just does nothing.

Accounts I have linked are google, twitter, facebook and linkedin.

Is there any conceivable reason why updates in the `people hub` sometimes work and sometimes don't?

Comment: The title indicates it's just twitter, while your question seems to point to a wider problem, is it JUST twitter in the people hub that isn't working or is it all updates?

Comment: It probably is all `people hub` `what's new` updates, or one of them that blocks all. I update the headline to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I try for these types of problems is to delink all accounts and relink them 1 at a time, checking to see if the people hub works. Often times issues like this are caused by the oAuth token being revoked by the external service for whatever reason. I won't say that's your problem, but it's pretty likely.